# Filter template text

Tags: filters

I'm trying to use `the_content` filter which works great on regular posts or pages with template files that use `the_content()` function. I'm trying to use `the_content` filter to change the text from a template file that doesn't call `the_content()` anywhere.

Is there a *hook* that I can use to filter text?

Comment: If the code doesn't call **the_content()** function. What are you trying to change? Is the text coming from a **meta field**?

Comment: Can you please be more precise.

Comment: The question you asked is not very clear so I was asking if the text you are trying to change is coming from a meta field or something else.

Comment: The template contains all the html, so let's say I have an url inside the template, and I want to use the the_content filter to modify that url. It doesn't work for html code that is inside the template, it only works for html generated by the_content function inside the template file.
(also, really appreciate the answers )

Answer (score 0):

More informations needed, but maybe you'll find it by using [global variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables). Like:

```
global $post;
var_dump($post);
```